# integrate simple java app with ADFS2

Tags: java, single-sign-on, adfs2.0

Can i use adfs2 with java application? I want to implement single-sign-on in java. I have read some articals where they have mentioned that you need .net framework .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this.

You can protect your Java application with a Java Identity Provider such as OpenSSO, OpenAM, Ping Identity etc. This will take care of the SSO for you. You then federate this provider with ADFS.

Or you can use the OpenSSO or OpenAM Fedlet [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17842_01/doc.1111/e17846/fedlet.htm) or [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17842_01/doc.1111/e17847/about.htm) which is essentially a SAML 2.0 stack. In this case, you could communicate directly with ADFS.

Or (as @Scott states), use one of the other products.

**Update:**

Using the Fedlet follows the normal SAML integration flow of exchanging metadata (ip / sp .xml). From an ADFS point of view, just install the sp.xml as a RP using the file. Just follow the Fedlet documentation substituting ADFS for OpenAM. There is no sample code (other than what's in the Fedlet). You don't actually have to write anything - it's a configuration exercise.

Comment: I am stuck up with the same problem please can you provide me with the sample code or use-case through which i can go about it.

Comment: There is no code - it's all configuration. Look here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17842_01/doc.1111/e17847/configjavasp.htm substituting ADFS for OpenAM

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Communication can be via SAML 2.0 which is widely supported by many toolkits and products.